# Async and await in javascript and node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, mern

I'm a beginner and doing a MERN tutorial and am having trouble understanding the control flow for the code below. What does async/await do in this function and when is user set to the awaited value (User.findById...)?

```
router.get('/', auth, async (req, res) => {
    const user = await User.findById(req.user.id).select('-password');
    res.json(user);
}
```

Comment: [async](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function) / [await](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/await) documentation **exists**, you just have to look for it

Comment: Note that async route handlers aren't supported in Express until 5.0 gets released; if there's an error in finding the user, your request will hang.

Answer (score 0):

An asynchronous function is a function which operates asynchronously via the event loop, using an implicit Promise to return its result. And the await operator is used to wait for a Promise. It can only be used inside an async function.

So in this exampleof async/await user "awaits" until User.findById() function returns result, as it will be somewhere in the future, and that is achieved with the help of await keyword.

I suggest to watch this video about the [event loop](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8aGhZQkoFbQ) to better understand how asynchronous JavaScript works.

Also I strongly encourage you to read MDN documentation
[async](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function) / [await](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/await)

And read about [Promises](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise)

If you'll have some further questions, I'll be happy to help you.